# jquery function not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

i'm trying to get a JQuery function running in IE7. In Firefox and Safari its working fine. Now i tried to debug, and even the simplest function is not working in IE, so i guess its a problem of the whole call.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('start in IE');
        fmmovement();
});
            </script>
```

The whole script website is http://project.formplusmedia.de/redesign

is there any trick to get this function running in the booring Internet Explorer? Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

regards

h-man24

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your script block change your type value to read:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

should fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies with the mime type you gave for Javascript.

You wrote `application/javascript`. **The only one that I know that works on all browsers is `text/javascript`.**

I had experienced this similarly before. I wrote `text/javscript` and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not recognize the application/javascript content-type. Use the old text/javascript content-type instead.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 does not understand "application/javascript" as a script type. You will have to use "text/javascript" for IE 6 and 7.

Answer (score -1):

Hai

hav you try to make it like a singlefile?

script.js and load it in you header (`<script src="js/script.js" type="application/javascript">`) after jquery.js file.

good lock